# Saving DTM to file using Save As to projected coordinate system shifts pixels between on-the-fly reprojection and export

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a DTM in EPSG:4326 which I extracted from a bigger one and everything until now is OK

[image]

Now I changed the map canvas projection to 32616 which is the one for the area I need and it seems to be working doing on the fly reprojection

[image]

Problem is when I save the DTM in the projection to do analysis the pixels are shifted thus the values do not correspond to what I saw before and if I query the pixels they differ which I want to avoid. I save it using the following
[image]

[image]
[image]

How do I keep my DTM raster aligned to how QGIS reprojects on the fly, as I am thinking that should be OK, or is it that the on-the-fly reprojection is not, correct?

Comment: Of course the values are different. Raster projection involves interpolation and physically different pixels.  You *can't* keep it aligned, because that's not possible.

Comment: On the fly reprojection is correct, but it is made to screen pixels in the map canvas. It is like reproject only the canvas extent of the source layer, to a new raster with a very little pixel size. If you do that you will see the same result in the same canvas size, but it is not what you want.

Comment: As a general rule you should work with DTM/DEM rasters in their original coordinate system, and then reproject (if necessary) the products of that work, such as a hillshade or slope raster.

Comment: I know raster reprojection will change the pixels, the question is why on the fly reprojection is different than saving to disk. Pixels size remains the same on both @GabrielDeLuca so something is off if I have everything on screen and pick on values, I get different set. I would want for both to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand what is happening we need to exaggerate it a bit.

Here I have a false DEM, but it meets the same conditions: It is in geographic coordinates, reprojected on the fly over a UTM zone:

[image: 1]

---

**The raster format is a regular rectangular grid of pixels.**

There are always the same number of rows for each column and viceversa.
The same goes for the screen and the same goes for the screenshot. But both on my screen and the screenshot file I uploaded, the pixels in my DEM don't look rectangular.

That is just an appearance. The resolution of the screen is just finer than the resolution of the DEM.

If we were to reproject at a resolution as fine as the screen, we would get the same result. But that's not what we want. We want to reproject to a similar resolution, just in another reference system. And this is the result:

[image: 2]

---

From here, it becomes clear what is happening.
The new grid effectively takes the value of the closest pixel. But due to the deformation, in some areas, pixels of different values overlap.
And it is possible to identify a point that takes a pixel from one raster but a neighboring pixel from the other:

[image: 3]

Comment: Ah that makes more sense, but this means that the on-the-fly reprojection (taking the screen resolution) is subdividing the pixels. Am I correct then that to have the same on the fly view once reprojected I would need to use a finer resolution. Would you be able to show an image based on what you did with a finer resolution to check the difference. This is very interesting

Comment: Reprojected to a 100 times small pixel: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJI2v.jpg. If you change the canvas zoom, then you will note it again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lioge.jpg. This is not a solution. It's just to find out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, now it seems this should be stated somewhere in the QGIS documentation that for rasters on the fly reprojection uses the screen pixels vs the raster resolution